# Warning C4800: 'int' : forcing value to bool 'true'

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Пытаюсь сделать следующее:

```
int A = 1;
bool B = (bool)A;
```

Получаю предупреждение при компиляции: warning C4800: 'int' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning). Почему? Как с ним бороться!?

Comment: Расскажите, зачем вам нужно превращать `int` в `bool`. Обычно это просто не нужно.

Comment: Используйте `A != 0`, см. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206564/what-is-the-performance-implication-of-converting-to-bool-in-c

Comment: @Котик: мой хрустальный шар говорит, что топикстартер пользовался бы `BOOL` вместо `bool` в таком случае.

Comment: А что говорит компилятор в случае использования static_cast ?

Comment: @VladD кыль в C++ есть тип данных bool, думаю имеет смысл использовать именно его а не int

Comment: A != 0 понятное дело, что будет работать! Почему предупреждение (bool)A ? Да ещё performance warning!

Comment: bool B=static_cast<bool>(A); - Тоже самое, предупреждение!

Comment: Я думаю, warning из-за того, что компилятор вынужден вставлять эквивалент `(А != 0)`, то есть, проверку, вместо преобразования типов "на месте", которое вообще с т. зр. ассемблера ничего не делает. Обычно cast практически "бесплатен": просто адрес в памяти интерпретируется по другому. Как написано в упомянутом топике на SO, другие компиляторы (кроме MSVC) такого warning'а не выдают.

Comment: Кстати, g++ не ругается (даже без приведения типа).

Comment: Я бы не обращал на это внимание. В конце концов приведение разных типов в булю - обычная и часто необходимая операция.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не въехал. Дело в том, что сейчас все компиляторы оптимизирующие. В данном контексте получается, что переменная A вообще не нужна. И компилятор запросто может просто свести все к `bool B = true;`. По крайней мере если код именно таков. Если не таков, то прошу привести более расширенный пример.

По предупреждению C4800 лучше всего ответит [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6801kcy.aspx).

> This warning is generated when a value that is not bool is assigned or coerced into type bool. Typically, this message is caused by assigning int variables to bool variables where the int variable contains only values true and false, and could be redeclared as type bool. If you cannot rewrite the expression to use type bool, then you can add "!=0" to the expression, which gives the expression type bool. Casting the expression to type bool will not disable the warning, which is by design.

Короче, по-простому, майкрософт говорит: "не пользуйтесь приведением к булевому типу". Вероятно проблема в том, что компилятору все равно нужно сделать лишнее действие. А именно вставить проверку `!=0`.

Comment: Думаю тут дело не в экономии действий компилятора, а в некой установке (в головах разработчиков) на то, как **надо** писать программы.

Comment: @gecube В моей функции используется strcpy_s и т.п. если вычисления прошли успешно то возвращаем true.
Тогда ещё один вопрос - если моя функция не возвращает код ошибки, а ограничивается ответом выполнено или нет, правильным и достаточным будет использования bool для возвращаемого значения!?

Comment: @rejie, думаю, что да, правильно.

Comment: @rejie, а Вы никогда не задумывались **почему** (*с какой целью*) оригинальная `strcpy()` возвращает адрес приемника?

Comment: @avp адрес приемника или NULL в случае ошибки, честно говоря не задумывался, для чего? И почему в strcpy_s делает иначе?

Comment: @rejie, возврат strcpy адреса позволяет написать компактную и красивую комбинацию функций. 

strcpy_s возвращает код ошибки, которой *в хорошо спроектированной* программе в данном месте все равно нет. Т.е. принципиально тут разговор о том, кто отвечает за ошибку - поставщик данных (функция проверяет корректность результата) или потребитель (функция проверяет аргументы).

Это некая перестраховка, попытка заставить не очень умелого программиста задуматься. Попытки научить **всех писать хорошо** предпринимаются уже лет 40, насколько они удачны - решайте сами.

Тема интересная, но места мало...

Answer (score 0):

Что вам непонятно в этом предупреждении? Он абсолютно вам намекает на неявное преобразование типа. Хотите так делать? Не проблема: используйте `static_cast` например или приведение в стиле Си (менее предпочтительно)